# Save large pandas dataframe to excel

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

I'm generating a large dataframe (1.5 GB when saved in CSV format) and need to store it an worksheet of an Excel file along with a second (much smaller) dataframe which is saved in a separate worksheet.

```
print('Reading temporaty files for variable {}:'.format(Var))
print(' Reading stations')
s=pd.read_csv(StatFile,sep=':',dtype={'ID': 'str'},encoding='utf-8')
print(' Reading data')
d=pd.read_csv(DataFile,sep=':',dtype='str',encoding='utf-8').transpose()
d.columns = d.iloc[0]
d=d[1:].astype('float')
d.reindex_axis(sorted(d.columns), axis=1)
print('Writing out Excel file for variable {}'.format(Var))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(Path + Var + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
d.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data')
OutStatCol=['ID','Name','Longitude','Latitude','GRS','OriginalVariable','VariableUnits','URL','JsonNode']
s.to_excel(writer, columns=OutStatCol, index=False, sheet_name='Stations')
writer.save()
```

My code works fine for smaller dataframes, but with the large ones I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Test2.py", line 29, in <module>
    writer.save()
  File "/home/user/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 1413, in save
    return self.book.close()
  File "/home/user/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 297, in close
    self._store_workbook()
  File "/home/user/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 624, in _store_workbook
    xlsx_file.write(os_filename, xml_filename)
  File "/home/user/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1148, in write
    self._writecheck(zinfo)
  File "/home/user/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 1114, in _writecheck
    " would require ZIP64 extensions")
zipfile.LargeZipFile: Filesize would require ZIP64 extensions
```

Is there any way I can specify something like `allowZip64=True` in the ExcelWriter declaration or in the to_excel() method?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried splitting it up in half?

Comment: I need the entire DataFrame stored in one worksheet and, if I understand correctly what you are suggesting, splitting it in half does not seem to achieve my goal...

Comment: almost there... it's a keyword you need in `pd.ExcelWriter(...)`

Comment: I tried both `allowZip64=True` as an option and `.use_zip64()` as an attribute... both returned errors

Comment: @user6357781 found it yo.. tell me if this works

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This took some source code digging, but...

```
print('Reading temporaty files for variable {}:'.format(Var))
print(' Reading stations')
s=pd.read_csv(StatFile,sep=':',dtype={'ID': 'str'},encoding='utf-8')
print(' Reading data')
d=pd.read_csv(DataFile,sep=':',dtype='str',encoding='utf-8').transpose()
d.columns = d.iloc[0]
d=d[1:].astype('float')
d.reindex_axis(sorted(d.columns), axis=1)
print('Writing out Excel file for variable {}'.format(Var))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(Path + Var + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

#THIS
writer.book.use_zip64()

d.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data')
OutStatCol=['ID','Name','Longitude','Latitude','GRS','OriginalVariable','VariableUnits','URL','JsonNode']
s.to_excel(writer, columns=OutStatCol, index=False, sheet_name='Stations')
writer.save()
```

should work

figuring out that the `writer` didn't inherit from workbook took me longer than it should have. `writer.book` is directly a workbook instance... d'oh

Comment: `ctl - f` is your best friend when looking through source... also notepad++ :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Unfortunately after a few hours of processing the final excel file ended up being corrupt... I'll run it again an check it I can g

Comment: I have the same issue, but this solution does not seem to work on Databricks. Any idea?

Comment: Same here, add `xl_writer.book.use_zip64()` but in the end the excel is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `engine='xlsxwriter'` to the function `.to_excel()` and it's fixed the problem.